# Qual a melhor forma de substituir um carácter numa determinada posição da String?

Tags: java, string

Preciso substituir um carácter numa determinada posição da String().

Exemplo - Trocar o caracter[21] por 'X':

**String Original** = 01078989469150999134B **B** 2116456

**String Modificada** = 01078989469150999134B **X** 2116456

Estou usando o seguinte código:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer('01078989469150999134BB2116456');
sb.setCharAt(21, 'X');
String novaStr = sb.toString();
```

Porém pelo que li e entendi, ficar utilizando StringBuffer() é custoso, principalmente nesse processo o qual será utilizado várias vezes (leitura de código de barras).

A pergunta é - Esse método é eficaz? Existe uma forma melhor e mais eficiente?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existem três opções de classes para manipular Strings: String, StringBuffer e StringBuilder.

Usa-se:

- String: quando não deseja ficar modificando muito o texto;
- StringBuilder quando deseja fazer inúmeras modificações no texto.
- StringBuffer quando deseja fazer inúmeras modificações no texto e que a variável seja thread-safe.

Logo, a classe mais eficiente para fazer modificações é a StringBuilder, entretanto você não deve optar por ela caso esteja usando a mesma variável por diferentes Threads ao mesmo tempo, que é o caso de se optar pela StringBuffer.

Se fosse o caso de estar executando essa operação apenas uma única vez no meio do seu código, a eficiência é algo que pouco importa. Portanto, qualquer uma das escolhas não alteraria muita coisa.

Como você disse que está fazendo a operação por inúmeras vezes, use o StringBuilder. A sintaxe é a mesma, veja o exemplo:

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder("01078989469150999134BB2116456");
s.setCharAt(21, 'X');
System.out.println(s.toString());
```

Answer (score 3):

Uma alternativa seria usar o `StringBuilder` ao invés do `StringBuffer`, pois a segunda utiliza métodos sincronizados e a primeira não, e como se sabe, a sincronização de métodos afeta o desempenho, visto que apenas uma thread acessa por vez cada método. Como ficaria o código:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("01078989469150999134BB2116456");
sb.setCharAt(21, 'X');
String novaString = sb.toString();
System.out.println(novaString);
```

Outra alternativa seria não usar nem `StringBuilder` e nem `StringBuffer`, só não saberei te informar sobre a questão do desempenho:

```
String codigo = "01078989469150999134BB2116456";
char[] codigoChar = codigo.toCharArray();
codigoChar[21] = 'X';
codigo = String.valueOf(codigoChar);
System.out.println(codigo);
```

Comment: A classe `AbstractStringBuilder` que é estendida tanto por `StringBuffer` como por `StringBuilder` usa internamente um array de `char`. Portanto a eficiência é praticamente a mesma, exceto pela chamada de método e a verificação de limites. O único problema de eficiência que pode haver em alguns casos é se a rotina converter `String` de e para `StringBuilder` a todo momento, isto é, uma implementação ruim iria criar um `StringBuilder`, alterar o caractere, executar o `toString` e repetir isso várias vezes, ao invés de fazer em "*batch*".

Comment: Obrigado pela contribuição, e desculpe a ignorância: o que seria "fazer em _batch_"?

Comment: Foi uma forma resumida de dizer que todos os caracteres deveriam ser alterados e somente depois o conteúdo deveria ser convertido para String. Escrevi desse jeito porque acabou o espaço do comentário e não queria escrever 2... :S

Comment: Tranquilo. Grato mais uma vez. =)

Answer (score 0):

De forma geral eu acabo por usar StringBuilder:

```
var theString = "ABCDEFGHIJ";
var aStringBuilder = new StringBuilder(theString);
aStringBuilder.Remove(3, 2);
aStringBuilder.Insert(3, "ZX");
theString = aStringBuilder.ToString();
```